# Could you please help me to highlight the selected HTML table row created dynamically through java script

Tags: javascript

Below is the JavaScript functionalities addRow() I have used to add the rows dynamically and now am trying to highlight the selected row with red color using rowhighlight() function.

/*Function to addRows dynamically to the HTML table*/

```
function addRow(msg)
{
    var table = document.getElementById("NotesFinancialSummary");
    var finSumArr1 = msg.split("^");
    var length = finSumArr1.length-1;
    alert("length"+ length);
    for(var i=1; i<finSumArr1.length; i++)
    {

        var rowValues1 = finSumArr1[i].split("|");
        tb=document.createElement("tbody");
        var tbody=document.createElement("tbody");
        table.appendChild(tbody);
        var tr=document.createElement("tr");
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
        for(var k=0;k<=10;k++)//adding data to table dynamically
        {       

            var td=document.createElement("td");
            tr.appendChild(td);
            var element1=rowValues1[k];
            td.innerHTML =element1;
            tr.onclick=function(){

            rowhighlight(this);//calling the rowhighlight function
            }

        }



       }




}


     function rowhighlight(x)
    {

        var index = x.rowIndex;
        document.getElementById("NotesFinancialSummary").rows     [index].style.backgroundColor = "red";



    }
```

Comment: what is it exactly you want? A function to highlight a row? Why not just add a class, or set the style attribute directly?

Comment: @PeterVR : that is what i have did by setting the style attribute but it is not working...suggest me some other way please...

Comment: Can you give us a demo page, or a fiddle. I suspect there is some other styling interfering with your highlight class. Does it work in other browsers? Have you inspected the live code to see what styling gets applied? Any console.log left in your js, that might prevent it from running in ie8...

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to first loop through the other rows and remove the styling (really should be a class) then apply the styling (again, class) to the selected row.

Here's one way of doing it:

```
function rowHighlight() {
    var selectedRows = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');

    for (var n = 0; n < selectedRows.length; n++) {
        selectedRows[n].className = '';
    }
    this.className = 'selected'
}
```

And here's a working example of it, though very simple: [fiddle time!](http://jsfiddle.net/33xx8/)

Comment: unfortunately the above said one is not working , am in IE8 dat might be the reason...Any other way ....please...